# Data from the encoder

Tags: ros, encoder, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to get the motor shaft turning data from the encoders, located inside the robot base using C ++ or Python?

Give a link to the answer if this question has been, please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226601/data-from-the-encoder/) by [UniverBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/25948/univerbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on what your robot is and what odom data it publishes. Check documentation for the robot you have, or use rostopic list see what topics are available. If you are writing nodes for a self built base then you will need to read the encoders and publish the data on a topic yourself.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UniverBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/25948/univerbot/) on 2016-02-16**:
I'm working with KUKA Youbot. The main goal is to get the angle of rotation of the motor shaft. The manual for this robot gives information only about how to convey information on the engines. And not a word about how to get it.